How to simulate data for a Bivariate Integer-Valued Auto Regressive process of order 1 time series in R?
I want to simulate data (Monte Carlo simulation) to assess the small sample properties of the Maximum Likelihood Estimators (MLE) for the BINAR(1) model:
\begin{aligned}
& Y_{1, t}=\rho_1 \cdot Y_{1, t-1}+R_{1, t} \
& Y_{2, t}=\rho_2 \cdot Y_{2, t-1}+R_{2, t}
\end{aligned}
The distribution for $R_{1, t}$ and $R_{2, t}$, the innovations, also known as the error terms has Poisson marginals connected through a Frank copula.
I aim to conduct simulations with two sample sizes: $n=200$ and $n=500$, each with 200 replications. The initial parameters for the BINAR model are:
$$
\rho_1=0.3, \quad \rho_2=0.7, \quad \lambda_1=1, \quad \lambda_2=1 \quad \delta=-1
$$
$\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are the parameters of the time series. $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the parameters of Poisson distribution. $\delta$ is the dependence parameter of the Frank copula.
I intend to use the 'optim' function for log-likelihood optimisation and the `stats' package in R to do this. From this simulation, I should be getting 5 values stated above for $n=200$ and 5 values for $n=500$.
Can someone please help me in implementing this process in R?
I have defined a function for the Frank copula as follows:
# This is the frank copula formula
pcopula.fam1<-function(u,v,a){
  - (1/a) * log(1 + ((exp(-a*u)-1) * (exp(-a*v)-1))/(exp(-a)-1))
} 

# This is a function for expressing the bivariate Poisson distribution connected via Frank copula
dmass<- function(x,y,l1,l2,a){ 
  a1<-pcopula.fam1(ppois(x,lambda=l1), ppois(y,lambda=l2),a)
  b<-pcopula.fam1(ppois(x-1,lambda=l1),ppois(y,lambda=l2),a)
  
  c1<-pcopula.fam1(ppois(x,lambda=l1),ppois(y-1,lambda=l2),a)
  d<-pcopula.fam1(ppois(x-1,lambda=l1),ppois(y-1,lambda=l2),a)
  a1-b-c1+d
}  

##### Log-likelihood (ML-estimators) #####
loglik<-function(theta){
  x<-x
  y<-y
  alp11<- exp(theta[1])/(1+exp(theta[1]))
  alp22<- exp(theta[2])/(1+exp(theta[2]))
  th1<-theta[3]
  th2<-theta[4]
  th3<-theta[5]
  p<-NULL
  for (i in 2:n){
    k<-rep(0:x[i],each=y[i]+1)
    s<-rep(0:y[i],x[i]+1)
    f1<-dbinom(x[i]-k,x[i-1],alp11)  # alpha1 is the probability of success, 'p', for the binomial distribution 
    f2<-dbinom(y[i]-s,y[i-1],alp22) # alpha2 is the probability of success, 'p', for the binomial distribution 
    f3<-dmass(k,s,th1,th2,th3) 
    p<-c(p,sum(f1*f2*f3))
  }
  -sum(log(p),na.rm=T)
}

